# How to user symfony-cmf/simple-cms-bundle in symfony3

Tags: symfony, composer-php, symfony-3.2, symfony-cmf

I want to use `symfony-cmf/simple-cms-bundle` in `symfony3.2` but It's support only `symfony2`. So I am looking to avoid check version at the time of development and will update on production.

Is it possible by pass validation through any configuration or command for temporary basis into composer or any other place.

Comment: Note that this bundle is not maintained anymore due to lacking resources of the CMF team. It might indeed not work with Symfony 3 in its current state.

Comment: thanks for information @dbu

Comment: have any other alternative of symfony-cmf/simple-cms-bundle?